# Experiences with IKVM.NET

Tags: java, .net, interop

Is [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) a good way to use Java Code or Java Libs in .NET applications?

Has anybody experiences with this tool? Are there alternatives? Are there possibilities to call Java functions/code in COM-based applications like Visual Basic 6 or Classical ASP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used this tool and especially the [compiler](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) to convert a JAR file to .NET assembly. It was for the [xhtmlrenderer](http://ostatic.com/xhtmlrenderer) project which allows to convert an XHTML file to PDF and is based on iText which is not a small code base. The conversion went fine and I am using it in production without any flaws.

Answer (score 5):

I've just started using this tool and it is quite amazing how it integrates .Net and Java. I was using it to convert a library that was only available in java to a .net assembly.

The good:

- Extremely easy to use
- Small footprint(the assemblies are not that big, and you don't need all of them all of the time)
- Project seems to be well maintained and the sourceforge feedback seems good

The bad:

- Debugging is a little more difficult. The Visual Studio exception handler looks for a message property that is blank in java. The result is that you have to make temporary try...catch block and put a watch on the exception object to inspect the details of the java exception
- classpath resources can be difficult to load and work with.
- Javadoc strings are not converted through so don't expect to see tips with intellisense, you will have to read through javadoc html to get help.

Overall it's been a pleasant experience, but I have admittedly only been using it for 2 days now.